# ui router is routing but not render the templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use UI-Router like this :

```
angular.module('app.user.awardee', [
    'ui.router'
])
    .config(
    [          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('awardees', {

                    abstract: true,
                    url: '/u/awardee',

                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/awardee.html',

                    resolve: {
                        awardees: ['awardees',
                            function( awardees){
                                return awardees.all();
                            }]
                    },


                    controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'users', 'utils',
                        function (  $scope,   $state,   users,   utils) {

                        }]
                })
                .state('awardees.personaldata', {
                    url: "/personaldata",
                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/personal_info/personal/view.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'utils', 'access',
                        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, utils, access) {

                        }]
                })
                .state('awardees.personaldata.edit', {
                    url: "/edit",
                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/personal_info/personal/edit.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'utils', 'access',
                        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, utils, access) {

                        }]
                })
                .state('awardees.univerisitydata', {
                    url: "/universitydata",
                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/personal_info/university/view.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'utils', 'access',
                        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, utils, access) {

                        }]
                })
                .state('awardees.universitydata.edit', {
                    url: "/edit",
                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/personal_info/university/edit.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'utils', 'access',
                        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, utils, access) {

                        }]
                })
                .state('awardees.bank', {
                    url: "/bank",
                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/personal_info/bank/view.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'utils', 'access',
                        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, utils, access) {

                        }]
                })
                .state('awardees.bank.edit', {
                    url: "/edit",
                    templateUrl: 'app/user/awardee/personal_info/bank/edit.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'utils', 'access',
                        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, utils, access) {

                        }]
                })

        }
    ]
);
```

i route from 'awardees.personaldata' to 'awardees.personaldata.edit',
the route is happend, url is changed but it not render 'awardees.personaldata.edit', it render 'awardees.personaldata'.
nothing error in console, 
what is my false? and how to make it work?

I Use This code to transition :

```
<a ui-sref="awardees.personaldata.edit" class="btn btn-hollow btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Personal Data</a>
```

Comment: how you are doing transition, you should use either `$state.go('awardees.personaldata.edit')` from controller & `ui-sref="awardees.personaldata.edit"` from html anchor

Comment: i use <a ui-sref="awardees.personaldata.edit">Edit</a>

Comment: Can you make a plnkr to replicate this? It looks fine, unless your `personal/edit.html` is identical to your `personal/view.html`.

Comment: Does `...awardee/personal_info/personal/view.html"` have a `ui-view`?

Comment: @NewDev no, it doesn't have.

Comment: @Tony no, in edit.html everything to be input, i just follow ui router example and customize it

Comment: @yozawiratama You should post your html for `personal/view.html` to confirm @New Dev's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would venture a guess that this, most likely, has to do with a missing `ui-view`.

The view of the parent state, in this case, `"awardees.personaldata"` has to have a `ui-view` somewhere for the child - `"awardees.personaldata.edit"` - to render its contents (just like `"awardees"` state's view has its `ui-view`, which I presume it does, since you can view `"awardees.personaldata"`).

So, make sure that in the template: `'app/user/awardee/personal_info/personal/view.html'` you have something like:

```
<div>
  <span>Some data from "awardees.personaldata" state</span>

  <!-- space to render "awardees.personaldata.edit" state -->
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow you are right, hmm it works but it to be something not i want.  i think the view.html will transition to edit.html. may be can you update your answer to be like that, please?

Comment: @yozawiratama, one way is to make it a sibling of "view", so it would render in the same `ui-view`